# How to handle two spring forms in one page with respective submit actions?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-form

I have two spring forms on one page with their own submit actions:

**JSP:**

```
<form:form id="frm_user_login" class="animated fadeIn" method="post" action="./loginsubmit.htm" commandName="useSignInFm">

<form:form id="frm_user_register" class="animated fadeIn" method="post" action="./registersubmit.htm" commandName="userRegistrationForm">
```

And their respective mappings in one Contoller:

**Contoller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginsubmit.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView signIn(@ModelAttribute("useSignInFm") SignInForm signInForm, BindingResult bindingResult,
        Model model, HttpServletRequest request)

@RequestMapping(value = "/registersubmit.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView userRegistration(@ModelAttribute("userRegistrationForm") UserRegistrationForm userRegistrationFm, 
        BindingResult bindingResult,Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
```

Submitting one form (`userRegistrationForm`) gives exception of other form:

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'useSignInFm' available as request attribute.
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: Could you maybe include more of the JSP, to also include how you're submitting the form? (With a normal `<input type="submit">` or something else? Your code looks right to me...

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, Spring does not support multiple forms in a single jsp. But I read a clever answer in another forum: Use a single `<form:form>` and switch `action` attribute via javascript on submit button press. The drawback is that you also need to manage the model that will require a modification of your form class. Alternatively you can simply go with AJAX, that simplifies the things alot.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're rendering two forms in one page, you need to bind them both in your controller mappings, otherwise the unbinded one will get lost while returning to the view, causing that error. The form backing objects must both exists when rendering the view.

So try this, it worked in my case, very similar to yours:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginsubmit.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView signIn(@Valid @ModelAttribute("useSignInFm") SignInForm signInForm, 
BindingResult bindingResult, @ModelAttribute("userRegistrationForm") 
UserRegistrationForm userRegistrationFm, Model model, HttpServletRequest request)

@RequestMapping(value = "/registersubmit.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView userRegistration(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userRegistrationForm") 
UserRegistrationForm userRegistrationFm, BindingResult bindingResult,
@ModelAttribute("useSignInFm") SignInForm signInForm, Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
```

Notice that I added the @Valid annotation because I assume that you want to validate the first form in each request mapping. Also be careful at the position of the bindingResult parameter: it must follow the @ModelAttribute parameter whose binding results you want to consider.

Answer (score -1):

> Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'useSignInFm' available as request attribute

means that , there is no element with id/name matching "useSignInFm". You should start fixing that first.

Comment: This is the problem @user5146398 is asking about - when he submits one form, his controller is expecting a request attribute of the other form.